# How do I fetch the records of those rows which have the maximum date value in mysql?

Tags: mysql

My sql query:

```
SELECT * FROM `electric_transaction` 
WHERE `Current Date`=(SELECT MAX(STR_TO_DATE(`Current Date`, '%d/%m/%Y')) 
FROM `electric_transaction`)
```

When I execute the above query, I get a list of warnings showing:

> Warning: #1292 Truncated incorrect datetime value: '01/04/2021'

> Warning: #1292 Truncated incorrect datetime value: '31/03/2021'...

I've even tried

```
 SELECT * FROM `electric_transaction` 
 WHERE `Current Date`=(SELECT MAX(`Current Date`) FROM 
 `electric_transaction`)
```

But, it just shows all the records which don't even have the maximum date. How do I fetch only those records which have the maximum date?

**Note:** My `Current Date` column is of type `VARCHAR` and the dates are in `d/m/Y` format

Comment: We need to see your data.  You should not be getting this error for the data and query shown.

Comment: My `Current Date` column is of type `VARCHAR` with values like `31/03/2021`,`01/04/2021`, etc

Comment: Convert the date to DATE datatype. The best way - correct your structure. Or use STR_TO_DATE() to the value in WHERE too.

Comment: Well I've used `STR_TO_DATE()` but as you can see in my post, I get a whole lot of warnings

Comment: ``WHERE `Current Date`=(SELECT DATE_FORMAT(MAX(STR_TO_DATE(`Current Date`, '%d/%m/%Y')), '%d/%m/%Y'))``

Comment: your first query had a subquery returning a date, and then was doing where string=date, which causes the string to be cast to a date resulting in those warnings.  your second query would not show all records as you say, I suspect you tried something a little different than you show.  but it will not find the latest date, as you want

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Akina this query works:

```
SELECT * FROM `electric_transaction` 
WHERE `Current Date`=
(SELECT DATE_FORMAT(MAX(STR_TO_DATE(`Current Date`, '%d/%m/%Y')),
 '%d/%m/%Y') FROM `electric_transaction`)
```

Comment: note that this will absolutely require those leading zeros; if you have a date stored as '1/4/2021' it will find the maximum date 2021-01-04 and format that as 01/04/2021 and find no matching records (or at least not the ones without zeros).  to be a little less persnickety, do `WHERE STR_TO_DATE(`Current Date`,'%d/%m/%Y') = (SELECT MAX(STR_TO_DATE(`Current Date`, '%d/%m/%Y'))...`